# iOS 7 weather app shows wrong sunrise/sunset time

Tags: ios, timezone

The new update for the weather app in iOS 7 is confused as to day/night, the time for sunrise/sunset. To find sunset or sunrise, swipe left or right on the hourly overview that's in the middle under the temperature / detail tap target.

[image]

For example, Selah WA says sunrise is at 10:46 pm today (4 October) and that it's dark at 3 pm.  Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried manually setting the time & region.

Comment: Time and region are correct.

Comment: Mine is doing the same thing for one city. It's been placing sunset at around 1 pm here, while the other 4 or 5 cities I have saved are correct.

Comment: Can someone name a city with faulty info, so we can try it and see if it is wrong for us as well?

Comment: Even more fundamental - what set of steps do you perform to obtain sunrise data using iOS 7's weather app? Editing that into the question might help greatly.

Comment: I have a problem with Selah, WA

Comment: @bmike When viewing a city in the Weather app, the side-scrolling list of hourly forecasts contains entries for both sunrise and sunset. For example, it will have entries for 6PM and 7PM with an icon representing the weather conditions, and the temperature in degrees. Between those will be an entry for sunset, labelled 6:45 PM.

Comment: Confirmed I can see the same problem when looking at Selah, WA's entry: it seems to think it's nighttime right now, despite it being mid-day. Problem seems isolated to that city; the rest of mine (Seattle, WA, for example) seem fine.

Answer (score 1):

The clear error would be a city in another state or country.

The sunrise and sunset data for [Minneapolis, KS](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sunrise%20minneapolis,%20ks) is going to be different than [Minneapolis, MN](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sunrise%20minneapolis,%20mn).

Once you have ruled that out, you might need to file a bug with Apple in the case that their app is either requesting the wrong data from the weather service provider or the data source needs to be corrected. In both cases, you can't really change what happens in code or upstream and could only try to find a location that's close enough for weather purposes that has correct (or close enough) sunrise and sunset data.

http://apple.com/feedback might also be workable rather than filing a bug if enough people have issues where the current data set is lacking or off by hours.

Answer (score -2):

If foregoing does not solve it: in Settings->General-Date&Time disable "set automatic time zone".